# For shared Nobel prizes, where does the medal go?

Tags: nobel-prize, academic-awards

When a Nobel prize is awarded to multiple people, the prize money is split. But what about the actual medal - how do they determine who will keep and store it? Been reading through the pages on [nobelprize.org](https://www.nobelprize.org/) but there is nothing concrete about this.

Comment: Perhaps they provide multiple medals?

Comment: They each get a medal with their [name engraved on it](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/about/the-nobel-medals-and-the-medal-for-the-prize-in-economic-sciences/).

Answer (score 1):

For shared nobel prize.....
Suppose two persons share a nobel prize then both will get a medal but prize money will be diveded in two parts depending upon contribution say 50% and 50% or 75% and 25% etc.